# Default value for reference argument in PHP function

Tags: php, reference

Is there any reliable way to know if a function reference argument has been passed?

I've seen answers here in Stack Overflow that suggest to give it a default value and check that value, but I've tested it and it's not 100% reliable because you can't check if the argument hasn't been set or if it has been set to a variable with the same value than the default one.

```
function fn (&$ref = null) {
    if ($ref === null)
        echo "ref null";
    else
        echo "ref not null";
}
$var = null;
fn($var); // ref null

function fn2 (&$ref = -1) {
    if ($ref === -1)
        echo "ref === -1";
    else
        echo "ref !== -1";
}
$var = -1;
fn2($var); // ref === -1
```

I'm running PHP 7.2

Comment: I don't think there are other languages that deal with this behavior...in php you could call `func_get_args()` and check if any parameters are passed. But in the end it shouldn't matter if the variable was set to null...the behavior should be the same

Comment: The behavior doesn't have to be the same in all cases. If your function has an optional output arg, you need to know if any variable has been passed to put the output value there. If the caller just create a new variable for that doing `$foo = null` and pass it as argument, you have to use it.

Comment: Other languages do allow it, maybe in a different way. In C++ you can overload a function this way `void foo()` and `void foo(int &bar)`, and the result is the same: optional reference argument (not the same kind of reference, but similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the number of arguments passed into the function using [`func_num_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

```
function fn (&$ref = null) {
    echo func_num_args().PHP_EOL;
    if ($ref === null)
        echo "ref null".PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "ref not null".PHP_EOL;
}
$var = null;
fn($var);
fn();
```

will give

```
1
ref null
0
ref null
```